# Can you convert strings for CSS color names to usable Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm working on a program that aims to use an array of colors (that are stored as strings). I need to take the strings and change the color of a piece of text to a random color.

Sample Array:
`let colorArray = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple"];`

My Function:

```
// "introduction" refers to the piece of HTML that is being changed
function onClickIntro()
{
    //returns a color from a random index in colorArray
    return introduction = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length())];
}
```

My goal is to use the strings from the array to change the color of a piece of HTML text. I've gotten nothing so far.

Comment: `length` is not a function. You can remove the `()`. You'll still need to set the values to CSS stylesheet or HTML element attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there.

Building on what you already have so far, you can apply the color, via:

```
// "introduction" refers to the piece of HTML that is being changed
function onClickIntro() {
  let newColorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length);
  let newColor = colorArray[newColorIndex];
  introduction.style.setProperty('color', newColor);
}
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the element that you want to change the color using [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or the way you find useful for your code and change its style properties [color](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp) or [background](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp):

```
function onClickIntro() {
  let element = //you get here the element you want to change its colors
  //Careful, .length is property, not a function()
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length); 
  element.style//.property you want to change = colorArray[randomIndex];
}
```

[Full example (use only if you get stuck after trying hard or after finishing your program)](https://codepen.io/raulpenate/pen/zYXzvRr)

*Happy coding!*